# Does there exist a branch of mathematics that specifically study the number of lattices enclosed by a region?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, soft-question

I have seen that sometimes, in particular in number theory and combinatorial commutative algebra, our questions are somehow related to finding the number of points with integer components in a region/shape. Since this seems to be related to some open problems and conjectures, does there exist a branch of mathematics that specifically study such questions? If yes, what it's called and what prerequisites one must know to study it.

Comment: The Geometry of Numbers is a common phrase in this context. At least for number theory.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Thanks. Yes, my book on number theory had a chapter about that but that isn't a branch of mathematics yet, am I right? Do you know any good books that are specifically about geometry of numbers?

Comment: In your title, you say "the number of lattices."  I think you mean "the number of lattice points."

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Yes, that's right.

Comment: "Geometry of numbers" has a [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers) so it could be thought of as a "real" branch of mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a square lattice, if you're counting the number of lattice points inside a polygon whose vertices are lattice points, then you can use [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem).  Other relevant theorems are [Blichfeldt's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlichfeldtsTheorem.html) and the [Minkowski Convex Body theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskiConvexBodyTheorem.html).

Some Wikipedia links that might help:
[Lattice (group)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28group%29),
[Integer points in convex polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_points_in_convex_polyhedra)

Answer (score 2):

In case that some people are interested to know more about 'geometry of numbers' I found some good books on the subject. Some of them were too long and advanced, so they require that you devote a good time on this subject, but the best book I found on this topic is "**The geometry of numbers**" written by **C.D. Olds**, **Anneli Lax** and **Giuliana P. Davidoff** which has been published by *The Mathematical Association of America*.

The topics that it covers includes:

Part I - Lattice points and number theory

Chapter 1 - Lattice points and Straight Lines

Chapter 2 - Counting Lattice points

Chapter 3 - Lattice points and the area of Polygons

Chapter 4 - Lattice points in Circles

Part II - An introduction to the geometry of numbers

Chapter 5 - Mikowski's fundamental theorem

Chapter 6 - Applications of Minkowski's theorems

Chapter 7 - Linear transformations and Integral Lattices

Chapter 8 - Geometric interpretations of Quadratic forms

Chapter 9 - A new principle in the Geometry of numbers

Chapter 10- A Minkowski Theorem(Optional)

Appendix I   - Gaussian Integers. by Peter D. Lax

Appendix II  - The closest packing of Convex Bodies

Appendix III - Brief biographies